# Why is Cloudflare waiting for name servers for over 4 days?

Tags: google-analytics

I've registered for Cloudflare's free plan and have completed the process of redirecting the DNS as instructed, including changing the name servers.
This was done 4 days ago.
The problem is that cloudflare is giving me:

"websites" -->

"Finishing up. Waiting for your name servers to change to ***** Please allow up to 24 hours to complete this process (info)"

"dashboards" -->

"Analytics data could not be loaded.

You do not have any initialized zones"

I can see via traceroute that CloudFlare is the DNS to my site.
Also, somehow this has messed up with my google analytics account so I have no idea if I get visitors to my site or not.

What should be done to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Please do consider just opening a ticket with us directly through our support system at https://cloudflare.com/support.

This is a dead simple issue for us to look up and to get you a solution. We obviously can't share details over here on a 3rd party site, but the typical reason is you already have the same domain signed up in a 2nd account with CloudFlare.

Please do open a support ticket, and we'll be happy to look into this for you.

P.S.: I work at CloudFlare.